# What is the name of your system with PHP_OS constant

Tags: configuration, php

I use PHP_OS constant and I want to know what it can return on differents OS.

I found this :

- On Linux -> Linux
- On FreeDSB -> FreeBSD
- On Windows NT -> WINNT
- On Mac Os X -> Darwin

Can anyone tell me what they get with them configurations ? On Solaris, Windows XP...

Comment: So you want to know what information can be read out of the information returned by `phpinfo`?

Comment: This is a terrible place to collect info like this. And you're talking about OS fingerprinting. Go try nmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [php_uname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) for retrieving operating system information

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record... I'm running on Windows XP and this is what's returned:

`PHP_OS` : `WINNT`

`php_uname('s')` : `Windows NT`

**UPDATE:** The same on Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

***Edit:*** This answer refers to an older version of this question, and may no longer be relevant.

The variants are so numerous as to be relatively useless for most sane applications; the "system" information is derived from a number of pieces of information about the environment, usually at compile time.

If you're looking to inspect the specific capabilities of the PHP configuration, you're better off querying specifics; checking configuration flags or for the existence of functions from extensions, etc.

**Note:** You mention `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. User-agent isn't the same as system; a user agent is the software running on the client that's issuing requests to the server - usually a web browser. User agent sniffing is an often invaluable tool for dealing with cross-browser compatibility issues.

Comment: For HTTP_USER_AGENT, I'm ok with you, it's cause I say "without use $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]"